# Как сделать owl карусели, одну с автопрокруткой другую без (dle 11.3)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap, dle

Поставил на сайт 3 карусели(на главной странице), работают хорошо, но возникла потребность кастомизировать каждую из них по отдельности,а именно хотел чтоб одна из них была с автопрокруткой и без кнопок а остальные с кнопками "влево-вправо" без автопрокрутки, посмотрел документацию, покопался в файле owl.carousel.min.js без проблем нашел нужные опции, но проблема в том, что когда указывается значение опции (autoPlay=true),то оно применяется для всех каруселей, тоесть либо все с автопрокруткой, либо без нее. Так вот вопрос: как вносить правки для конкретного блока карусели, чтоб они не влияли на остальные блоки?

Comment: для каждой карусели задайте разный class (или id) и вызывайте карусель. Пример https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/hgk5y8w5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этой карусели установлена автоматическая прокрутка

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".owl-carousel-1").owlCarousel({
          autoplay:true
        });
    });
```

Для этой автоматическая прокрутка отключена, как и по-умолчанию

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".owl-carousel-2").owlCarousel({
          autoplay:false
        });
    });
```

Comment: Спасибо, добавил в js файл и все работает, только у Вас в примере кода надо исправить на "autoPlay" , а то не хотел работать

Comment: Возможно разные версии карусели.
Я взял этот параметр из документации на оф. сайте.

Comment: может кто будет читать, у меня 1я версия